# SVG text element text fit in circle border

Tags: javascript, svg

when i create dynamically svg  text circle is working fine in  number.but i am using small letter (example:- ffffffiiiisasdasdas) text circle   create half but i need full circle and Shape should be react according to content which we are placing   .. 
please check image following
1.http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15fll6b&s=8 
2.http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fe1181&s=8

following code use

```
<svg width="845" height="350" viewBox="0 0 845 350"       clip-rule="nonzero"     >
    <g 
        data-ng-attr-fill="{{addText.color}}" 
        data-ng-attr-width="{{addText.w}}"
        data-ng-attr-height="{{addText.h}}"
        data-ng-attr-transform="{{rotate(addText)}}"
        strok  <defs>

        <path stroke-width = "3"
              fill="userSpaceOnUse"
              data-ng-attr-id="temp-{{addText.id}}"
              data-ng-attr-d="{{makeBox1(addText, true)}}" />
        </defs>
        <text ng-if="addText.text"  glyph-orientation-vertical="90" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" "
              data-ng-attr-text-anchor="{{addText.text.anchor}}"
              data-ng-attr-font-family="{{addText.text.font}}"
              data-ng-attr-font-style="{{addText.text.italic ? 'italic' : 'none'}}"
              data-ng-attr-font-weight="{{addText.text.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal'}}"
              data-ng-attr-font-size="{{addText.text.size}}"
              data-ng-attr-x="{{arcMid(addText)}}"
              letter-spacing="2";
              style="text-align:justify"
              kerning="8">

            <textPath data-ng-xlink-href="#temp-{{addText.id}}"  method = "stretch"
                      writing-mode="lr-tb"  clip-rule="nonzero"  xlink:href="">
                {{addText.text.text}}</textPath>
        </text>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#EEE" data-ng-attr-d="{{makeBox1(addText,true)}}"  />
    </g>
</svg>
```

javascript

```
$scope.makeBox1 = function makeBox1(item, temp) {

    if (item.c == 1) {


        var ma = $('#txtsearch').val();
        var legth = ma.length;

        console.log(legth + "m");
        if (item.r == 0) {
            item.r = item.h / 2;
        }
        var x1 = item.x + item.w / 2,
            y1 = item.y + (item.h),
            x2 = x1 + 1,
            r = item.r;
        if (temp) {
            x1 = 270 + item.w / 2;
            y1 = 30 + (item.h);
            x2 = x1 + 1;
        }

        item.r = ((((((legth) * item.text.size * 5) / (legth / 0.9))) * legth * .02) + (legth * 0.09));
        if (item.r > 137) {

            item.r = 137;
        }
        x1 = 424.5;
        y1 = 293;
        r = item.r;
        x2 = 425.5;
        var y2 = 293




        return "M " + x1 + " " + y1 + " " +
               "A " + r + " " + r + " 0 1 1 " + x2 + " " + y2;
    }  
    }
```

Comment: What is the question...?

Comment: i want svg text circle this grow with content.....

Comment: i want create dynamically   svg text  element it grow content with size.....  please check image :-this image working fine  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15fll6b&s=8#.VGRvoTSUcmc  but this image not working  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fe1181&s=8

Comment: Video url:-  http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=i6mlwp%3E&s=8#.VGRypTSUcmc[^]

Answer (score 2):

It's working for numbers because they always have a fixed width - or almost always.  That is because you typically want numbers to align in columns - in invoices for instance.

Your complicated equation for calculating the circle radius is based on the font size.  The formula has obviously been tweaked so it works well with the width of numerals in the font you are using.  But it won't work with general non-numeric text.  Or probably with numerals in a different font.

It is going to be hard to get this to work perfectly in every case, because different browsers may implement their `<textPath>` elements differently.

The best you can do is to measure the text length, and then calculate the radius from that, by dividing by (2*PI).

You can get the length of the text in a `<text>` element by calling `getComputedTextLength()` on the element.

```js
var msg="ffffffiiiisasdasdas";

// Get SVG
var  mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

// Get text length
var tmp = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
tmp.textContent = msg;
mysvg.appendChild(tmp);
var  len = tmp.getComputedTextLength();
mysvg.removeChild(tmp);
//alert("len = "+len);

// Make the circle path for the msg to sit on
var  x1 = 424.5,
     y1 = 293,
     x2 = 425.5,
     y2 = 293;
var  r = len / (2 * Math.PI);
var circ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
circ.setAttribute("id", "circ");
circ.setAttribute("d", "M " + x1 + " " + y1 + " " +
                       "A " + r + " " + r + " 0 1 1 " + x2 + " " + y2);
mysvg.appendChild(circ);

// Make the textPath element
var  tp1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
mysvg.appendChild(tp1);
var  tp2= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath");
tp2.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#circ");
tp2.textContent = msg;
tp1.appendChild(tp2);
```

```css
svg text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#circ {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" width="845" height="350" viewBox="0 0 845 350">
</svg>
```

Comment: same issue on this formula .. full circle create in number and letter on create half circle .....

Comment: BigBadaboom:- could you give me you skypid or contact no or email id

Comment: It works for me.  See the code example I just added.

Comment: how to create half circle on this think